# ng-bootstrap accordion : How to add class to wrapper of nbg-pannel?

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-bootstrap, angular9

I want to add a class('open') to the wrapper(ie. 'card' class) of the ngb-panel selector when ngb-panel is expanded.
How can I achieve that?

As per my research, I have used

```
(panelChange)='panelShadow($event)'
```

event to  get the active panel (ie. expanded panel ) as below:

```
{panelId: "panel2", nextState: true, preventDefault: ƒ}
panelId: "panel2"
nextState: true
preventDefault: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Now: I want to **add** class **"open"** with already existed class **.card** to the expanded panel

**I want output like this...**
[image]

[stackblitz] Live demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-ngb-accordion-expanded-shadow)

Comment: Can you post the code of the component and the function panelShadow($event) ?

Comment: I have added the [stackblitz] link for live code.. you can see there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-ngb-accordion-expanded-shadow-problem

maybe  this is not the best approach, but it do the job by extending your own code just by removing unnecessary .open class added when each card is going closed.

**update**: 
 to make the snippet compatible with a by-default active panel...
1. the `cardClass="open"` added to the `ngb-panel` element of the active panel
2. main logic updated as the following

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

export interface NgbPanelChangeEvent {
  nextState: boolean;
  panelId: string;
  preventDefault: () => void;
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  lastPanelId: string = null;
  defaultPanelId: string = "panel2";

  panelShadow($event: NgbPanelChangeEvent, shadow) {
    console.log($event);

    const { nextState } = $event;

    const activePanelId = $event.panelId;
    const activePanelElem = document.getElementById(activePanelId);

    if (!shadow.isExpanded(activePanelId)) {
      activePanelElem.parentElement.classList.add("open");
    }

    if(!this.lastPanelId) this.lastPanelId = this.defaultPanelId;

    if (this.lastPanelId) {
      const lastPanelElem = document.getElementById(this.lastPanelId);

      if (this.lastPanelId === activePanelId && nextState === false)
        activePanelElem.parentElement.classList.remove("open");
      else if (this.lastPanelId !== activePanelId && nextState === true) {
        lastPanelElem.parentElement.classList.remove("open");
      }

    }

    this.lastPanelId = $event.panelId;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... brother, Your solution worked... :)

Comment: I have one issue:  By default { activeIds="panelShadow2" } is open, so, By default, I am unable to add class open to that card.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it again, it should now support a by-default active panel.

Comment: Thank you @HoseinGhanbari for a quick update. I went through your code and when I updated `defaultPanelId: string = "panel1";` and `activeIds="panel1"`, still isn't working..  even with other active panel ID's isn't working. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're welcome. Do you add `cardClass="open"` to `ngb-panel`? also check the stackblitz demo, it's working as expected.

Comment: Thanks once again.. As you suggested I forgot to add `cardClass="open"` to `ngb-panel`, Now it's working absolutely fine.. ~ cheers